# Как заставить компилятор пересчитывать пути (compilerOptions.paths) в относительные?

Tags: typescript

Я сделал библиотеку компонент под React на TypeScript. В файле **tsconfig.json** прописал следующее:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
...
"paths": {
  "@lib": ["src/lib"],
  "@lib/*": ["src/lib/*"]
}
```

Теперь вместо

```
import {} from '../../../from/field/ComboBox';
```

я пишу более кратко:

```
import {} from '@lib/from/field/ComboBox';
```

Во время разработки эти пути нормально вычисляются. Но после сборки и публикации пакета в другом проекте, где данная библиотека подключена, появляется ошибка:

```
build/dist/lib/form/combo/ComboBox.d.ts
(3,40): Cannot find module '@lib/form/list/List'.
```

Как сделать, чтобы при сборке компилятор эти пути пересчитывал на относительные?

Comment: чтобы сделать либу на typescript есть миллион туториалов в гугле - почему бы вам сперва там не поискать? `paths` - это просто алиас, который говорит компилятору, где искать нужный(е) файл(ы), к тому же если бы вы читали документацию по `module resolution`, то увидели бы, что `paths in the final output do not match their corresponding source file paths at compile time`

Comment: @overthesanity К сожалению ваш комментарий не помогает решить эту проблему. Причем либу делаешь или просто программу все равно одна и та же проблема ---- опция path какая-то бесполезная, потому что на этапе разработки все работает, а на этапе сборки - ничего не пересчитывается.

Comment: свойство `paths` работает и на продакшене, только это не относится к разработке библиотек, я чисто из интереса только что попробовал этот гайд https://www.tsmean.com/articles/how-to-write-a-typescript-library/ с использованием `paths` - все работает

Comment: @overthesanity если у вас получилось, то написали бы развернутый ответ. А то не ясно как это вообще возможно без сторонних средств сделать.

Comment: ничего у него не получилось, по приведённой им ссылке paths не используется. просто у TS реально есть косяки, и это, всего навсего, один из них

Answer (score -2):

Возможный вариант решения проблемы:

Самоделка из чата (примечательно что используется ts-simple-ast):
https://gist.github.com/rifler/e6123e90e172814fe23d5a6a11ed5eb1

Но пока уперся в то, что не ясно как работать с файлами .d.ts

AST позволяет работать с файлами .ts

Comment: Возможно по ссылке и можно найти ответ на вопрос, но лучше опубликовать решение прямо в ответе. Ссылка со временем может измениться, либо станет вовсе недоступна для последующего просмотра.

Comment: @Anamnian спасибо за замечание. Чуть позже, когда выберу самый удобный вариант, заменю текст ответа на расширенный без ссылок.